# Azure AD - create a new Service Principal programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, service-principal

I'm writing a python script to provision and configure Azure services. I would like to provision a new Service Principal as a part of my script but have issues with permissions. If I run this command in my terminal (after `azure login`), it will create the Service Principal:

`az ad sp create-for-rbac --name Testapp`

I want to achieve the same, but in my python script, where I'm using existing service principal for the resource provisioning. The calls I'm making are as follows:

```
call("az login --service-principal -u '%s' -p '%s' --tenant '%s'" % (args.client_id, args.client_sec, args.tenant_id), shell=True)
call("az ad sp create-for-rbac --name TestServicePrincipal", shell=True)
```

The arguments are the credentials of the existing service principal. This service principal is already `OWNER` of that subscription as you can see here:

[image]

When running my python script, I do login just fine (also with those credentials I can provision a bunch of other resources via the script), but I will get permission errors when creating the SP account as you can see here:

```
synergies git:(master) ✗ python test.py -c 'testcustomer' -l 'eastus' -sid '1234' -cs '1234' -cid '1234' -tid '1234'
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "1234",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Free Trial",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "1234",
    "user": {
      "name": "1234",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
Changing "TestServicePrincipal" to a valid URI of "http://TestServicePrincipal", which is the required format used for service principal names
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Just let me know if you have any other concerns regarding this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer @TonyJu, really appreciate the time you took to help out! You were right, that I did not have the SP with granted permissions for `Application.ReadWrite.All` and it did make perfect sense to add it and I thought things will work, however, I'm still getting the exact same error: `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`. I even created a new SP app and set it up with the required permissions, but still the same permission issue error. I then tried to add bunch of more permissions for the Graph, but no difference. Not sure there is anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked it out on my side. You need to assign `Global administrator` role to your sp. **Note: This will take several minutes to take effect**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Does it work for you without any errors? I did as you suggested - created a new SP app and assigned app administrator role. Now, when I run the script, it will still throw the same permission error but with a more context, but at the same time it will create the SP app - tried a few times and always the same issue - error but SP is created.

`Creating service principal failed for appid 'http://petristesting2'. Trace followed:
{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma':....Insufficient privileges to complete the operation` -> the trace continues, just not enough space in the comment.

Comment: @PetrHecko assign the sp Global administrator role will solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the Global Administrator fixed the last issue! @Tony Ju